# php random comment generator

Tags: php, random, comments, chat

This make seem a little odd, but is there any script kicking about that generates random comments, kind of like chat room comments.

Random stuff like "im bored", "hey people", "gonna log cya", "anyone seen the film *_*".

Anyone ever come across anything like this?

Comment: Create a list of comments in a Database or in an array and choose a random index each time to select a random comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
$comments = array("Im bored", "Hey people", "Gonna log cya", "Anyone seen the film");
$random_comment = array_rand($comments);

echo $comments[$random_comment];
```

---

If you have a MySQL table with comments, you can do the following:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `comment` FROM `comments` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1");
if($result) echo mysql_result($result, 0);
```

Comment: order by rand() is too much expensive

Comment: @ran - It **is** expensive. But we can't make an assumption that is its **too** expensive with out seeing the context.

Answer (score 3):

You could *generate* random comments by combining a random selection from two arrays.

One for a [personal pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_pronoun) and one for an action/verb...

```
$pronoun = array(
 "I'm",
 "You're"
 "He's",
 "She's",
 "They're"
);

$action = array(
 "stacking",
 "overflowing",
 "confused",
 "bewildered",
 "wondering how many more of these I can make up",
 "getting bored... So that's enough for now..."
);
```

Running [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) once on each of those arrays will return a random index and concatenating the corresponding values will generate a comment.  You'll have to beef out the arrays and suit them to your needs.

```
$comment = $pronoun[array_rand($pronoun)] . ' ' . $action[array_rand($action)];
```

---

Creating a comment generator function will further ease the process of using this system -

```
function generateComment(){
  global $pronoun,$action;
  return $pronoun[array_rand($pronoun)] . ' ' . $action[array_rand($action)]
}
```

Comment: `array_rand()` returns a random index, not a value. It should be `$comment = $pronoun[array_rand($pronoun)].' '.$action[array_rand($action)];`

Answer (score 1):

```
$comments = array("Im bored", "Hey people", "Gonna log cya", "Anyone seen the film");
shuffle($comments);

echo $comments[0];//1,2,3.....
```